# Decoding using MultiLabelBinarizer python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

My target is a data frame that looks like the one below, using MultiLabelBinarizer to encode the my data frame (each row at once) works well, while decoding always outputs data in wrong order.

Here is a simple data frame (my target y):

```
index   col2         col2     col3
0       Anton        230      DR
1       Leila        890      DR
2       Arjun        688      ENG
```

Example from sklearn webiste

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
encoded = mlb.fit_transform([['sci-fi', 'thriller', 'comedy']])
mlb.inverse_transform(encoded)

Ouput:
array(['comedy''sci-fi','thriller'])

The desired output should be:
['sci-fi', 'thriller', 'comedy']  ** NOT ** ['comedy''sci-fi','thriller']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try printing the encoded variable. I believe the trouble you have is that the function is turning the string "sci-fi" into a sequence of characters. The function "fit transform" takes as input a "iterable of iterables".

If I am correct then the simple fix is this:

```
encoded = mlb.fit_transform([['sci-fi'], ['thriller'], ['comedy']])
```

Comment: Thanks but that is definitely not the right answer/reason. Please give your answer a try on e.g. Jupyter